# Strategy to extract movies's name from this ununiform dataset?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, regular-expression

I am working on a movie database problem to improve regular expressions, this is the problem I'm running into. My dataset looks like this:

> Movie Name (variable space and tabs)  year
>   **Movie1**(can have spaces or multiple spaces between them)(variable spaces and tabs could be \t+ or multiple space or single space> **Year1**
>   **Movie2**(can have spaces or multiple spaces between them)(variable spaces and tabs could be \t+ or multiple space or single space> **Year2**
>   **Movie3**(can have spaces or multiple spaces between them)(variable spaces and tabs could be \t+ or multiple space or single space> **Year3**
>   **Movie4**(can have spaces or multiple spaces between them)(variable spaces and tabs could be \t+ or multiple space or single space> **Year4**

I want to extract names of all of the movies. These are the challenges I'm facing while doing it:

> 1: The delimiter is variable. If it was colon or something unique, I would have used an awk command to extract them like this awk -F 'separator' '{print $1}'
>  In this case, it can be single space, two or more spaces or combination of \t or spaces.
>
> 2: For those rows where delimiter is  \t, I can use a \t to extract it, because that does not come in movie names.  But what if the delimiter is one space or two spaces. They can very easily appear in the movie's name. In those cases, I don't know what to do.

I know the question is very rigid and specific. But as I described earlier, I'm very much blocked here. I can't think of any way around this problem.

Is there any combination of grep/sed/awk with reg-ex that can be used to achieve the objective?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your description. Could you post a few actual sample lines that illustrate the variety?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `gawk` and assuming that the year always ends the record:

```
awk -F"[0-9]{4}$" '{print $1}' movies
```

Answer (score 6):

bash:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (.*)[[:blank:]]+[0-9]{4}$ ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done < data
```

sed:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+[0-9]\{4\}$//' < data
```

Comment: I like the bash approach. It is really good. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is really quite simple. As long as the last field, the year, does not contain any whitespace (this is not clear from your question but I am assuming it is the case), all you need to do is remove the last field. For example:

```
$ cat movies
Casablanca  1942
Eternal Sunshine        of the Spotless Mind            2004
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand                       2001
The Blues Brothers 1980
```

So, if you want to print just the title, you can use:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/[^\s]+$//' movies
Casablanca  
Eternal Sunshine        of the Spotless Mind            
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand                       
The Blues Brothers 

$ sed 's/[^ \t]*$//' movies 
Casablanca  
Eternal Sunshine        of the Spotless Mind            
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand                       
The Blues Brothers
```

or, to collapse the whitespace in the titles as well:

```
$ sed -r 's/[\t ]+/ /g;s/[^ \t]*$//' movies 
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers 

$ perl -lpe 's/\s+/ /g;s/[^\s]+$//' movies
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers 

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++){printf "%s ",$i} print $(NF-1)}' movies
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers
```

If the year is always 4 digits, you can use

```
$ perl -lpe 's/....$//' movies 
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers
```

or

```
$ perl -lpe 's/\s+/ /g;s/....$//' movies 
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers
```

or

```
$ while read line; do echo ${line%%????}; done < movies|od -c 
Casablanca 
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind 
He Died with a Felafel in His Hand 
The Blues Brothers
```

Comment: @terdon, for the `while` loop what happens when the movie name is 2012?

Comment: @Ramesh it will fail. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it and made some other improvements too.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the movie data will look something like below.

```
cat movies
one flew over the cuckoo's nest          1975
taxi driver      1976
the shining    1980
```

Now, I also assume the years in the movie data will always be 4 characters at the end.

So, now if you use the commands as below,

```
 awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}' movies | rev | cut -c 5- | rev
```

The output would be,

```
oneflewoverthecuckoo'snest
taxidriver
theshining
```

**EDIT:**

However, the best approach would be,

```
rev movies | cut -c5- | rev
one flew over the cuckoo's nest          
taxi driver      
the shining
```

Of course, I assume the year in your data will always be 4 characters. If it is always the same number of characters you could follow the second approach as it even maintains the spaces in the movie names.

Answer (score 1):

This should remove the last numeric characters and the tabs and spaces before it:

```
sed -e 's#[\t ]*[0-9]*$##' movies.txt
```